# Resources not found exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, resources

So i get the following crash when loading my app:

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-05 18:56:56.457 2545-2545/com.example.wessel.weer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.wessel.weer, PID: 2545
                                                                   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
                                                                       at com.example.wessel.weer.MainActivity.serviceSuccess(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                       at com.example.wessel.weer.service.YahooWeatherService$1.onPostExecute(YahooWeatherService.java:91)
                                                                       at com.example.wessel.weer.service.YahooWeatherService$1.onPostExecute(YahooWeatherService.java:40)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I believe the problem has to do with my Resources.java, which is filled with a total of 219 errors and 31 warnings.

Most, if not all errors in resources.java are:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'symbol name here'
```

For example:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'DrawableRes'
```

at

```
public Drawable getDrawable(@DrawableRes int id) throws NotFoundException {
```

I have already tried creating a new project and copying the old classes but it's the same problem.

Mainactivity code as requested:

```
package com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.wessel.weer.R;
import com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.data.Channel;
import com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.data.Item;
import com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.service.WeatherServiceCallback;
import com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.service.YahooWeatherService;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WeatherServiceCallback {

private ImageView weatherIconImageView;
private TextView temperatureTextView;
private TextView conditionTextView;
private TextView locationTextView;

private YahooWeatherService service;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    weatherIconImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.weatherIconImageView);
    temperatureTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperatureTextView);
    conditionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.conditionTextView);
    locationTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationTextView);

    service = new YahooWeatherService(this);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Laden...");
    dialog.show();

    service.refreshWeather("Austin, TX");
}

@Override
public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel) {
    dialog.hide();

    Item item = channel.getItem();
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/icon_" + item.getCondition().getCode(), null, getPackageName());

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Drawable weatherIconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);

    weatherIconImageView.setImageDrawable(weatherIconDrawable);

    temperatureTextView.setText(item.getCondition().getTemperature()+ "\u00B0" +channel.getUnits().getTemperature());
    conditionTextView.setText(item.getCondition().getDescription());
    //conditionTextView.setText(condition.getDescription());
    locationTextView.setText(service.getLocation());
}

@Override
public void serviceFailure(Exception exception) {
    dialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Error after using the suggested solution:

```
                 --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie, PID: 2446
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
                  at com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.MainActivity.serviceSuccess(MainActivity.java:53)
                  at com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.service.YahooWeatherService$1.onPostExecute(YahooWeatherService.java:87)
                  at com.example.wessel.weerapplicatie.service.YahooWeatherService$1.onPostExecute(YahooWeatherService.java:36)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Could you share your activity code ?

Comment: Just edited that in, shuvro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

It says:

> The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

So clearly what you get in resourceId is not a valid resourceId.
Log what you get from the service and look if you have exact resource in drawables.

Also you may me lacking @ here:

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/icon_" + item.getCondition().getCode(), null, getPackageName());
```

you can also use

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + item.getCondition().getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: How would i log what i get from the service?

Comment: Log.d("TAG",""+item.getCondition().getCode()); Then check if you have @drawable/icon_[what you've got]

Comment: also see my edited answer. That could be the case as well

Comment: Tried the way you suggested, edited in the  new error

Comment: It seems the same to me. What did you change exactly?

Comment: I tried changing something in activity_main but i undid those actions

Comment: how about changing the line to the one I've added to my answer?

Comment: I've changed the line to your last one, the 'you can also use' one. I'll check back later once i get home. Should we discuss this somewhere in a chat?

Comment: So i've checked what all these errors are.. I have the following problem with my Resources.java: http://imgur.com/a/Y6auc (album consists of 3 screenshots for reference)

Comment: Some serious issues are going on. I've noticed you're using bleeding edge software. Downgrade to stable android studio 2.1, use 23 API and stable build tools to make sure that it isn't what is causing the issue.

Comment: I've done that, it's now 218 errors and 31 messages in resources.java though (used to be 219 errors). I've also tried cleaning/building a lot of times.